# looking for code revision gui/application for my eclipse subversion

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, revision

I was wondering if anyone can recommend any GUI/portal/platform/application that shows code revisions. I'm using subversion with my eclipse and wonder if there's something nice such as trac to see the changes.

Thanks

screenshot example from trac (I found it extremely hard to install)

http://www.linuxlinks.com/portal/content/reviews/Programming/Screenshot-Trac.png

*sorry, since I'm a newbie, I can't embed the picture

Comment: Why dont you just use the diff viewer from within eclipse? If youre using subclipse juse select the file/folder and right click then do "Compare with".

Comment: I do and it works fine, but if I'm at home and wish to see some changes - I can't do it without eclipse.

Comment: I see... well as you mentioned, there is Trac, there is also [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/). Im sure there are others as well but those are the two that ive used and are relatively easy to set up (Redmine moreso than Trac IMO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [WebSVN](http://websvn.tigris.org/) and it works great. I've put it at the same host as my repository and access it through standard apache. WebSVN is free.

Then there is [FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/overview) from Atlassian. It's not free but I don't doubt it's one of the best ones available.

Answer (score 0):

What about good old [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/)? Not only it shows revisions, but also it's a great implementation of subversion client for eclipse with such functionality as: commit, update, branch, merge, etc. Not mentioning extended visualization capabilities. It seems that you do not use [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) while you definitely should.